One of monitors turns black when taking screenshot with spectacle
When pressing a hotkey to capture a region, or when using the UI button, in Spectacle on Ubuntu 24.04 with KDE Neon (manully installed), one of my monitors turns black. I then have to replug it in or disable-enable in the settings.
There are three monitors: laptop's built-in, a Philips connected via USB-C -> HDMI (works) and an MSI connected via HDMI (doesn't work)
I tried to:

unplug/disable all other screens including built-in laptop screen
remove all hotkeys and only use the capture UI button (to diagnose potential hotkey conflicts)
install spectacle from snap store instead of the bundled one (doesn't work with KDE Neon)
use shutter instead (doesn't work on Wayland)
use flameshot instead (doesn't work with multiple monitors)
reset all monitors' scale to 100%

Notably:

it only happens to one particular monitor (independent of monitor arrangement or the output it is plugged into)
running spectacle -m or capturing the "current screen" does not cause the issue, it is only region capture that does
running spectacle -r also turns the monitor black
even though the screen turns black, the output is still correct (the screenshot of the region is properly taken)
after going black, the monitor is still connected (does not show "awaiting input")
for a split second, I can see the capturing overlay, then the screen goes black
it is not shut off, the backlight is visible, its just black
locking the computer and unlocking it does not restore the image

This started happening after I switched from KDE to KDE Neon. I might've broken some dependency of spectacle in the process, but I'm not sure how to check that, and the spectacle logs have no errors.
Restarting the PC after installing upgrades. Now every restart fixes the issue temporarily. After a restart, everything works, then after some time stops and breaks (I'm still trying to find the exact action that breaks it)
Edit: Using "PixelTaken" as an alternative, the issue is also present.

Does Neon/NobleUpgrades help?

After the upgrade and system restart it was working for a while, then I tried it again 2 minutes later and it was broken again

Take a picture, i.e, cause the issue on purpose then use journalctl -b or journalctl --since <5 minutes before screenshot> to see if the logs give any hints.

I don't see anything useful. The spectacle logs themselves look identical before and after it breaks. (And are the same as running spectacle from the terminal) -- I also had a situation where I restarted, spectacle worked fine the first time I used it and only broke some time after.
Also, I just had the "luck" of opening spectacle region capture two consecutive times, the first worked, second broke. no logs between them in journalctl, no difference between spectacle logs between the two runs.

See Bug 462860 -
Rectangle capture modes have wrong GUI sizing and positioning with fractional scaling.  Is this what's happening?

That bug report mentions setting all monitors to 100% as a workaround, but in my case that doesn't work. Also the last comment mentions that issue was fixed in Spectacle 24.02, and I'm using Spectacle 24.08.

Was that the issue though?  If so, you need to file a new bug, or reopen the one that's closed.
